# Source "operator-filter-registry/src/DefaultOperatorFilterer.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

can you please help me how to solve this error?

I tried using the ./ for the path but it didn't worked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcH19.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.